# Slack-Api File Upload - Error No_File_Data

Tags: java, quarkus, slack-api, microprofile

I created a call to slack's api, but I'm getting no_file_data error, I've tested my file and it is being generated, I've sent it with filename in multiform, with filetype, but the error persists

CLASSE MICROPOFILE (client):

```
@Path("/slack")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "open-co.scd.integration.slack.api.scd-report-file")
@RegisterProvider(BaseExceptionMapper.class)
public interface SCDReportFileUploadClient {

  @POST
  @Path("/files.upload")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Response sendFileUpload(
      @MultipartForm SlackReportFileUploadRequest requestBody,
      @HeaderParam("Authorization") String token);
}
```

CLASSE DO FORM:

```
public class SlackReportFileUploadRequest {

  @FormParam("file")
  @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  private InputStream file;

  @FormParam("channels")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  private String channels;

  @FormParam("filename")
  private String fileName;

  @FormParam("filetype")
  private String fileType = "text";

  public SlackReportFileUploadRequest() {}

  public SlackReportFileUploadRequest(
      InputStream file, String channels, String fileName, String fileType) {
    this.file = file;
    this.channels = channels;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.fileType = fileType;
  }

  public InputStream getFile() {
    return file;
  }

  public void setFile(InputStream file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  public String getChannels() {
    return channels;
  }

  public void setChannels(String channels) {
    this.channels = channels;
  }

  public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
  }

  public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
  }

  public String getFileType() {
    return fileType;
  }

  public void setFileType(String fileType) {
    this.fileType = fileType;
  }
}
```

CLASSE REQUEST:

```
.
.
.
  public Response sendFileReport(byte[] content, String fileName) throws IOException {
    return fileUploadClient.sendFileUpload(requestBodySendFile(content, fileName, channels), token);
  }


  private SlackReportFileUploadRequest requestBodySendFile(
      byte[] content, String fileName, String channels) throws IOException {

    SlackReportFileUploadRequest buildForm = new SlackReportFileUploadRequest();
    buildForm.setFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
    buildForm.setChannels(channels);
    buildForm.setFileName(fileName);

    return buildForm;
  }
.
.
.
```

I need a generalist class that I can send files like .txt and .csv

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by leaving it like this

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "open-co.scd.integration.slack.api.scd-report-file")
@RegisterProvider(BaseExceptionMapper.class)
@RegisterProvider(MultipartFormDataWriter.class)
public interface SCDReportFileUploadClient {

  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  Response sendFileUpload(
      @MultipartForm SlackReportFileUploadRequest requestBody,
      @HeaderParam("Authorization") String token);
}
```

and

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SlackReportFileUploadRequest {

  @FormParam("content")
  @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  private InputStream content;

  @FormParam("channels")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  private String channels;

  @FormParam("title")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  private String fileName;
}
```